# Passing params to React Router not rendering the page via Link

Tags: reactjs

I am bit new to react and was developing an application using React-Router v4. The problem is coming when, I am clicking on the Link based generated component and it will take me to another page using parameters passed in the url, but the page is showing blank.

Here is my Link Tag:

```
return storedArray.map((url,index) =>
            <Link to={'/dashboard/siteInfo/' + url.pid + '/' + url.cid}  className="list-group-item list-group-item-action hover" key={index}>
                <div className="media">
                    <div className="media-body">
                        <strong>{url.pid}</strong>
                        <div className="text-muted smaller">{url.submitted_on}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Link>
        );
```

and my Router's code :

```
<Router>
            <div>
                <NavBar />
                <div className="content-wrapper">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                            <Switch>
                                <Route  path="/dashboard/siteInfo/:pid/:cid" render={ props => <SiteInfo {...props} />} />
                                <Route exact path="/dashboard/urls/:pid/:cid" component={Urls}  />
                                <Route exact path="/dashboard/queue/:pid/:cid" component={Queue}  />
                            </Switch>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</Router>
```

and i am hitting url via clicking -http://localhost:8080/dashboard/siteInfo/opensenselabs/2

Any help on this topic would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant to your situation, but I would suggest replacing your string with the string to={ \`tilda/dashboard/siteInfo/${url.pid}/${url.cid}\` }

Comment: Hi. The easiest way to check what's happening is to replace this `render={ props => <SiteInfo {...props} />} ` with this `render={ props => {console.log(props); return null; }} `, then you will know if the route actually triggers